# How do I access values in a complex nested multi value python dictonary

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, square

- I have a dictionary format below. It is a single line, but I formatted it here. Notice the nested Key "SshPublicKeys" that has itself a nested key-value group in square brackets.

```
{
    'ServerId': 'string',
    'User': {
        'HomeDirectory': 'string',
        'SshPublicKeys': [
            {
                'DateImported': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                'SshPublicKeyId': '123'
            },
                        {
                'DateImported': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
                'SshPublicKeyId': '456'
            },
        ],
        'UserName': 'string'
    }
}
```

- In this format, how do I access all the "SshPublicKeyId" key-value pairs? The final output should look like the below or just close to it.

```
'SshPublicKeyId': '123' 
'SshPublicKeyId': '456'
```

Comment: it'll help if you could share your code and what error did you face in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for public_key in dicta["User"]["SshPublicKeys"]:
    print(f"'SshPublicKeyId': '{public_key['SshPublicKeyId']}'")
```

Output:

```
'SshPublicKeyId': '123'
'SshPublicKeyId': '456'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res = [{'SshPublicKeyId': x['SshPublicKeyId']} for x in d['User']['SshPublicKeys']]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'SshPublicKeyId': '123'}, {'SshPublicKeyId': '456'}]
```

If you want output as string

```
res = ['SshPublicKeyId: ' + x['SshPublicKeyId'] for x in d['User']['SshPublicKeys']]
```

**Output:**

```
['SshPublicKeyId: 123', 'SshPublicKeyId: 456']
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by chaining element access as shown below.

Assuming the main dictionary is named `d`, to access the `'User'` dictionary you will need to do `d['User']`, i.e.:

```
d['User'] = {
    'HomeDirectory': 'string',
    'SshPublicKeys': [
        {
            'DateImported': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'SshPublicKeyId': '123'
        },
        {
            'DateImported': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
            'SshPublicKeyId': '456'
        },
    ],
    'UserName': 'string
}
```

To access the `'SshPublicKeys'` list of `d['User']` do  `d['User']['SshPublicKeys']`, i.e.:

```
d['User']['SshPublicKeys'] = [
    {
        'DateImported': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'SshPublicKeyId': '123'
    },
    {
        'DateImported': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
        'SshPublicKeyId': '456'
    },
]
```

Now to access the first dictionary of `d['User']['SshPublicKeys']` you will need to do `d['User']['SshPublicKeys'][0]`, i.e.:

```
d['User']['SshPublicKeys'][0] = {
    'DateImported': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'SshPublicKeyId': '123'
}
```

Finally, as you may have guessed already, to get `'SshPublicKeyId'` do `d['User']['SshPublicKeys'][0]['SshPublicKeyId']`, i.e.:

```
>>> d['User']['SshPublicKeys'][0]['SshPublicKeyId']
'123'
```

Similarly, `d['User']['SshPublicKeys'][1]['SshPublicKeyId'] == '456'` and so on.

---

It will be better (and shorter) to write a function **OR** store a reference to `d['User']['SshPublicKeys']` and index it if you need to do it repeatedly -- whichever suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions can be very useful in your case:

```
 [user_key['SshPublicKeyId'] 
 for user_key in main_dict['User']['SshPublicKeys']]
```